# Bernoulli effect: how to calculate the force which lifts a piece of paper

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Imagine a piece of paper in the x-y-plane over which there is a flow of air in lets say x-direction, like in this video:
https://youtu.be/BWvGE238DdE
Of course there is the explanation with Bernoullis principle for an ideal fluid Wich can be obtained e.g. from Euler's equations :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle

And there is really good explanations for Bernoullis principle out on YouTube:
https://youtu.be/LBdtIvqWkLw

However I wonder how to calculate the force on the piece of paper using the continuum mechanics approach of integrating the momentum flux density over the surface of the paper instead of using the Bernoullis principle. I want to obtain the force on the piece of paper using the stress tensor. How would I do this?
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: It is not difficult to determine the force acting on a flat surface from the side of the jet. But it will be difficult to determine the movement of the paper.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "integrating the momentum flux density over the surface of the paper instead of using the Bernoullis principle".